# Github Revert Not Updating

Tags: git, github

What I've currently done to my branch is the following:

- Reverted back to a commit in Github Desktop
- Logged on via the console
- Tried `git status` and it says I'm up-to-date **but** I'm actually on the commit that I just reverted still.
- I've tried to pull, change branch then come back but still stays the same.
- The commit is viewable on github.com in commit history.

Any help to get on the same commit would be great!

Comment: Did you push your revert commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by doing the following:

```
git fetch origin
git pull origin <BRANCH NAME>
git commit -a
```

I'm now up to date with the branch that is online.

Thanks